# EACESS error writing to file..ANDROID

Tags: android

Ok. Thank you.

Here's what I managed....

```
    String[] perms = {"android.permission. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};

    int permsRequestCode = 200;

   requestPermissions(perms, permsRequestCode);



  public void convertFile(Uri urx)
        throws IOException {

    ContentResolver test = getContentResolver();
    InputStream initialStream =  test.openInputStream(urx);


    byte[] buffer = new byte[initialStream.available()];
    initialStream.read(buffer);

    File xpath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);


    File targetFile = new File(xpath, "/test.mp4");
    OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
    outStream.write(buffer);
    uploadFile(targetFile.getPath());

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults){

    switch(permsRequestCode){

        case 200:

            boolean writeAccepted = grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

            break;

    }

}
```

I get an EACES error upon trying to write my .mp4 file. Is there a way to "write it to memory" ? Or maybe you can resolve this issue.